# Graph Valid Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree

I am attempting the LeetCode problem - [Graph Valid Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/graph-valid-tree/). I am able to pass all test cases except the last one (43/44):

Nodes: 10 and
Edges: [[5,6],[0,2],[1,7],[5,9],[1,8],[3,4],[0,6],[0,7],[0,3],[8,9]]

The output should be **false**

My solution is below. I check for a cycle and then check if I can reach all nodes starting at vertex 0. Any help to point out what I am missing or made a mistake on will be helpful.

```
public boolean validTree(int n, int[][] edges) {

    boolean cycleFound = checkCycle(n, edges);
    boolean isConnected = checkConnected(n, edges);
    if (!cycleFound && isConnected)
        return true;
    return false;
}

private boolean checkConnected(int n, int[][] edges) {
    HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = this.createAdjList(n, edges, true);
    // We start at the root and try to go to each node;
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    queue.add(0);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Integer current = queue.poll();
        visited.add(current);
        ArrayList<Integer> neighbours = adjList.get(current);
        int size = neighbours.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            Integer temp = neighbours.get(j);
            if (!visited.contains(temp))
                queue.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return visited.size() == n ? true : false;
}

private boolean checkCycle(int n, int[][] edges) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = this.createAdjList(n, edges, false);
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> visiting = new HashSet<Integer>();
    queue.add(0);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Integer current = queue.poll();
        if (visiting.contains(current) || visited.contains(current))
            return true;
        visiting.add(current);
        ArrayList<Integer> neighbours = adjList.get(current);
        int size = neighbours.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Integer temp = neighbours.get(i);
            queue.add(temp);
        }
        visited.add(current);
        visiting.remove(current);
    }
    return false;
}

private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> createAdjList(int n, int[][] edges, boolean forCycle) {
    // create the adjaceny list
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        adjList.put(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        int[] edge = edges[i];
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = adjList.get(edge[0]);
        temp.add(edge[1]);
        adjList.put(edge[0], temp);

        if (forCycle) {
            temp = adjList.get(edge[1]);
            temp.add(edge[0]);
            adjList.put(edge[1], temp);
        }
    }

    return adjList;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug? try printing `cycleFound` and `isConnected`.

Comment: also, you can just return `!cycleFound && isConnected`

Comment: @Ofek I get false for cycle and true for connected which returns true. From looking at the graph it seems there is no cycle and it appears to be connected.

Comment: there is a cycle: 0,7,1,8,9,5,6,0 try adding prints for some values and see where you see something you don't expect

Comment: hint: try printing `adjList`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you made the list `adjList` only with half of the edges, I fixed it by removing the parameter `forCycle`.

I also fixed some parts of your code and wrote comments so you will understand.

```
private boolean checkConnected(int n, int[][] edges) {
    HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = this.createAdjList(n, edges);
    // We start at the root and try to go to each node;
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    queue.add(0);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Integer current = queue.poll();
        visited.add(current);
        ArrayList<Integer> neighbours = adjList.get(current);
        int size = neighbours.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            Integer temp = neighbours.get(j);
            if (!visited.contains(temp))
                queue.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return visited.size() == n;
}

private boolean checkCycle(int n, int[][] edges) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = this.createAdjList(n, edges);
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer>();
    queue.add(0);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Integer current = queue.poll();
        if (visited.contains(current))
            return true;
        ArrayList<Integer> neighbours = adjList.get(current);
        queue.addAll(neighbours);// simpler
//      int size = neighbours.size();
//      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
//          Integer temp = neighbours.get(i);
//          queue.add(temp);
//      }
        visited.add(current);
    }
    return false;
}

// removed the boolean argument (this made your issue)
// you always want both direction of the graph
private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> createAdjList(int n, int[][] edges) {
    // create the adjaceny list
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        adjList.put(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        int[] edge = edges[i];
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = adjList.get(edge[0]);
        temp.add(edge[1]);
//      adjList.put(edge[0], temp); not needed

        temp = adjList.get(edge[1]);
        temp.add(edge[0]);
//      adjList.put(edge[1], temp); not needed

        /*
         * the code i commented is not needed because of how references works
         *
         * for example
         * if you do something like this:
         *
         * ArrayList<Integer> l0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         * l1 = l0;
         * l1.add(5);
         * System.out.println(l0);
         *
         * you will get the output: [5]
         * this happens because the variables are referencing to the same point in the memory,
         * so if you change one, you change the other.
         *
         * try look out on how references works
         */
    }

    return adjList;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the change helped unfortunately